# REG - Run Remote batch file from local machine in java

Tags: java, batch-file, processbuilder, winrm

I have executed batch file from command prompt with winrs command it was executed well, when i execute same command with java program using process builder, i am getting IOException like the specified path is not available 
Error 2 Specified path is not availble

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\winrs.exe -r:http://ipaddress:port -u:username -p:password dir": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specifiedProgram terminated!

at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
at com.sample.CmdExec.main(CmdExec.java:28)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
... 2 more
```

Answer (score 0):

ProcessBuilder does not use a complete command line like

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("cmd /c C:\Windows\System32\winrs.exe -r:http://ipaddress:port -u:username -p:password dir");
```

but needs the executable and the parameters separate:

```
ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "C:\Windows\System32\winrs.exe", "-r:http://ipaddress:port", "-u:username", "-p:password", "dir");
```